# why onChange event does not have event.keyCode property in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to disable spaces in the input text field using `onChange` event and react-hooks. I'm saving the email input in state. The function in `onChange` event dispatches action, passing `e.target` as its input. However as soon as the dispatch occurs, the input field gets reset. I have tested the input field and it is working fine but when I click the keyboard space button then `event.keyCode` and event.which gives me undefined value.

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';

const initialState = {
    email: ''
};

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'email':
            return {
                ...state,
                email: action.payload
            };
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}

const Login = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode == 32) {
            return false;
        }
        dispatch({ type: event.target.name, payload: event.target.value.trim() });
    }
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <input 
                type="email"
                name="email"
                value={state.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="Enter Email"
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That would be because `change` is not a [keyboard](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events) event.

Try using `onKeyDown`, `onKeyPress`, `onKeyUp` if you want the pressed key.

---

for example

```js
const Login = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const handleChange = event => {
    dispatch({ type: event.target.name, payload: event.target.value.trim() });
  };
  const handleKeyDown = event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 32) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        value={state.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        placeholder="Enter Email"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: @MohdAmir just added a snippet that uses `onKeyDown` and cancels the event if a space is pressed, but keep in mind that a user could copy paste something with spaces inside and your code would not handle that..

Comment: No need to add onKeyDown action .trim() will work in this case.

Comment: @MohdAmir `trim` will work in your current use-case although it will trigger `change` when no change has occured. For the copy paste the space could be between strings and so trim will not affect it.

Comment: But onKeyDown gives unidentified result in some cases: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14512

Comment: `onKeyPress` is deprecated [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event).